# How to process only specific lines from a .csv file?

Tags: python

I need to do some calculations using a .csv file. The first 4 rows of the file are header information, so actual data starts at row 5 down to row 80,000+, and I will be calculating averages for specific columns. How do I only process lines after the header information?

This is part of my code so far:

```
for datafile in datafolder:
    # open file in read mode
    o_csvFile = open(datafile)
    # get the 5th line 
    fifthLine = linecache.getline(roverFile, 5)
    # use while loop to read each line in file
    startReading >= fifthLine
    while startReading:
        line = o_csvFile.readline()
```

Answer (score 1):

With Pandas you can use the `skiprows` argument of [`read_csv()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) to begin after a set of header rows:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv("data.csv", skiprows=4)
```